# REGEXP_SUBSTR return full string in case comma delimiter is part of the string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to modify below query in order to get a correct value in case comma delimiter is part of the string ?

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('141001,update PRDTBL set a10=''141001'' where A03=''62'' and FIX_FLT=''1'' AND SUBSTR(TXN_ID,1,2)=''LN'' AND A05=''N'',62,1,LN,,,,N,FXL BUSINESS (M),FIXED LOANS - OTHERS,,DBA,2013-09-25,DBA,2013-09-25', 
'([^,]*)(,|$)', 1,2, 'i', 1)
FROM DUAL
```

above query will return value :

```
update portfldb set a10='141001' where A03='62' and FIX_FLT='1' AND  SUBSTR(TXN_ID
```

Expected value should be:

```
update portfldb set a10='141001' where A03='62' and FIX_FLT='1' AND SUBSTR(TXN_ID,1,2)='LN' AND A05='N'
```

Comment: Could you describe in your own words how to distinguish the commata you want to include in the result from those used as a separator?

Comment: CAN set like this, any comma within bracket should be part of a string. In this case, start from update till the end of the comma is a full string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there are no nested parentheses in your statement you could try with something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('141001,update PRDTBL set a10=''141001'' where A03=''62'' and FIX_FLT=''1'' AND SUBSTR(TXN_ID,1,2)=''LN'' AND A05=''N'',62,1,LN,,,,N,FXL BUSINESS (M),FIXED LOANS - OTHERS,,DBA,2013-09-25,DBA,2013-09-25', 
'([^,\(]*(\([^\)]*\)[^,\(]*)*)(,|$)', 1,2, 'i', 1)
FROM DUAL;
```

If there might be nested parentheses you won't get anywhere using regular expressions - you're out of luck then :-(